# getText of the generated textview after applying custom fonts

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-typeface

I am developing an app where normal text is converted to braille text and later i want the converted text to be printed into a pdf.

Currently i have just converted text by using a custom font for braille

```
tvTo.setText(edFrom.getText().toString());
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "braille_outline.ttf");
tvTo.setTypeface(font);
```

Now, when i want to print this text i just did

```
String toPrint = tvTo.getText().toString();
```

But this results in normal text rather then the converted typeface font.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you can use canvas and paint to draw text with typeface and save it as bitmap or sth else

Comment: could you give me any proper example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about generating a PDF.  But I don't think a TextView will help you here.  Instead, to draw your text directly to a bitmap, you can set a typeface on a Paint:

```
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
textPaint.setTypeface(font);
```

and then draw your text on a `Canvas`, if it is short:

```
canvas.drawText(string, 0, 0, textPaint)
```

If it's longer and you need the lines to wrap, use a `StaticLayout` and draw that to the canvas.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer with proper example, it feels this would be the only workaround here but i am not getting is properly.

Comment: @WilsonChristian this code is what i say you should draw your text on canvase and generate your output from canvas i cant share you code of writing text on image and save it but i have no idea for save it as pdf if you need my code( write on image) ill share it with you (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

toString returns a string.  Strings are just arrays of characters (basically), they don't have font information.  getText() returns a character sequence, that can include spannables that set fonts and other styles.  If you need to track fonts, you need to work at that level.  I'm not sure if getText will by default return a spannable for the font that was set, but you can easily put the text into a TypefaceSpan.

Comment: sadly, getText() won't return font information set on the TextView, and a TypefaceSpan is only for system fonts ...